# How to read a string that with single quote and apostrophe by pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have question about pandas read_csv function. The case is that I have some csvfiles which contains string like `'my friend's pet is a dog, Husky'`. There is a comma in single quote but in quotes there is a apostrophe.
How could I use read_csv to read the data as below:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,'my friend's pet is a dog, Husky',True,'Tom'
```

The files are very large I don't know which column contain string like this.

Thanks!

```
product_csv = pd.read_csv(DIR_NAME, quotechar="'")
```

when I run this line, I get the result as below:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4
1,'my friend's pet is a dog','Husky',True
```

Comment: That's not a valid CSV. Ideally, you'd want to fix whatever produced that file. Failing that, you'd need to create a parser yourself, since `read_csv` will only work on valid CSV files (or try to error-correct as much as possible).

Comment: Thanks! But why this csv file is not a valid CSV, and how should I use ' symbol to express 's or s' in a string

Comment: First of all, "CSV" is used in two senses: the strict is "comma separated values" as defined by [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt); the second is a semi-standardised collection of similar formats, which should really be called "delimiter-separated values". Both require that, if the delimiter is found inside a field, the delimiter should be doubled. Thus, your data should say `1,'my friend''s pet is a dog, Husky',True,'Tom'` to be read correctly. Thus, I reiterate: the best way to fix this is to fix whatever is producing non-compliant data. Use CSV libraries, don't make your own.

Comment: as @Amadan said you can write a custom parser function and then apply it over the dataframe column

Comment: @Amadan Thank you very much. so the reason is the data does meet specifications. To solve this problem I should fix the data in CSV file

Comment: @AnkitKumarNamdeo Thank you, do you mean that I should write a parser function like shell script to modified 's or s' into the correct specification? I can not  fix it in a df column because I can not use read_csv to create a df

Comment: Writing a parser to parse incorrect data is considerably more difficult than correctly writing CSV data in the first place. If the number of errors is small, you might be able to discover the offending rows and fix them manually; if it is large, the probability is high that you'd be trying to unspill milk.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you, I have already notified my colleagues who produce the csv. Thanks again.

Comment: Pandas doesn't have issues reading this kind of string. You don't even need to do anything special for it to do so.